# Protractor: SendKeys fails when FileDetector is enabled (Error: Uploading directories is not supported"

Tags: selenium, protractor, saucelabs, browserstack

I am currently running my Protractor tests on SauceLabs and BrowserStack and have FileDetector configured so that I can run tests that involve uploading files.

I am getting an error that says 'Uploading directories is not supported" when I try to use sendKeys() to write a message in a textarea.  I do not get this error when FileDetector is not included in the page.  To clarify, I am not doing any uploading at all when this error occurs - just trying to add text to a textarea.

Also, sendKeys does work in certain instances but not in others.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, did you used, element(by.model('login.user_name')).sendKeys('text'); ? and can you be more clearer about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a bug! Issue was fixed in:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1814

Answer (score 0):

The file detector will fail if used with a server that only supports standard WebDriver commands (such as the ChromeDriver). 
That might be reason why your sendKeys does work in certain instances.

You may refer following link:-

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html#sendKeys